# What does "Instantaneous Angle" means

Tags: signal-analysis

My teacher said to me that Instantaneous Angle means Argument of Complex Function thats all. Someone please tell me what significance does this "instantaneous" Word has here ?

Comment: was this function over time?

Comment: $f(t)$=$e^{j{({\Omega}t+\Phi_0})}$ where $${{\Omega}t+\Phi_0}$$ is instantaneous angle

Comment: great. It's instantaneous at time $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Instantaneous usually means the value of something right at this time. I think what this means in your case is that the function $f(t)$ is complex and you are taking the argument (finding the angle):
$$
\theta(t) = \arg\left( f(t) \right) = {\rm atan}(\Im[f(t)],\Re[f(t)])
$$
where $\Im[ \cdot ]$ indicates taking the imaginary part and $\Re[ \cdot ]$ indicates taking the real part.